# Cannot get comboboxes working properly within a child form? VB

Tags: vb.net, combobox, parent-child, mdichild, mdiparent

I have spent a long time trying to find a solution for the problem I am having with comboboxes within a child form. I'm sure this must be a Microsoft error and not something I'm doing wrong... I would really appreciate some help, Thanks in advance...

The best way to explain the problem would be to tell you what I have done so far:

If you open a new Project in VB and add two Windows Forms. Form1 will be the parent. Form2 will be the child.

On Form1 add 1 x panel(Form2 will open up within the panel so make sure the panel is big enough to fit Form2) and 1 x button. The only code needed for this form is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Form2.Show()

End Sub
```

On Form2 Add one Textbox and one combobox. Copy the following code into Form2:

```
Private Sub Form2_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus

    ActivateMdiChild(Me)

End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    TopLevel = False
    Form1.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me)
    Me.BringToFront()

End Sub
```

Now run the program and click button1 to open form2 (form2 should now open within panel1).

The comboboxes and textboxes lose some of there functions for example: 
 1. You cant set focus on combobox without hitting drop-down
 2. You cant highlight text properly in either the combobox or textbox.
 3. You cant set the cursor index position using your mouse in the combobox or text box.

Does anyone know a way around this?? Mainly for the combobox as I've got some functions working for the textbox.

Regards,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Your click event should probably look something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim f As New Form2
  f.TopLevel = False
  f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
  f.Visible = True
  Panel1.Controls.Add(f)
  f.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

and you can pretty much discard the code you have posted for Form2.  Moving a form that is an MDI child of the parent to a child control of a panel is a bit awkward.  I'm guessing that is not what you are really trying to do.

Also, this current code will just keep putting a new Form2 over any existing controls or forms that are already in the panel.  Make sure to dispose of unwanted controls.

Comment: Thanks LarsTech, I've changed this in my program now.. Do you know how I can fix the combobox/textbox errors I posted about?

Comment: Also when you set dockstyle to fill you cannot change the size of the childform so I have taken that line out

Comment: @Ben I can't repro the errors.  My ComboBox in Form2 works just fine inside the panel.  Changing the `TopLevel` property of the form after showing it probably has weird side effects.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help anyway, I'm still having the same issues at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the functionality you are trying to get on `Form2` is to set `Form1` as an MDI container through the `IsMdiContainer` property on `Form1`. You could then call `Form2` in the `Form1` button click with something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f As New Form2()
    f.MdiParent = Me
    f.Show()
End Sub
```

This would obviously create a new instance of `Form2` every time you click Button1, so you could change the click actions to `Form2.Show()` and in `Form2` constructor set the `MdiParent` to `Form1`. That should only create one instance of `Form2`.

I'm curious why you're mimicking MDI functionality through the Panel?

Comment: Thanks for your help Dave, I have now changed my program so that it no longer adds forms to the panel.
The reason why I needed to have the panel as the parent was purely for formatting issues. I's quite hard to explain without you actually seeing my program.